# How can i declare object in an if statement and use it wherever i want?

Tags: c++, class

```
if(i == 'y')class objectname();
if(j == 'n')class objectname(something);
objectname.getName();
```

How is possible to declare objects in an if, and use it in somewhere else? Because if i do like that **'objectname' was not declared in this scope;** 
Thank you

Comment: Then declare it in the surrounding scope? Also thats most definitly not valid C++.

Comment: Note that `class objectname();` declares a function named `objectname` that takes no arguments and returns `class`. It does not define an object. That's not the problem here, though.

Answer (score 5):

> How is possible to declare objects in an if [statement].

It's not, you can't conditionally declare anything.  What you probably want is to create a `class` (or group of `class`es controlled through an interface `class`) whose behavior is dependent on your boolean condition (or have `class`es in the group with each `class`'s behaviour dependent on a single condition if there's more than one condition ).

Comment: A class should usually only have one behaviour.

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 Quite right, answer corrected.

Comment: It looks like OP is just calling a different constructor, not creating a different type. They probably just need some constructor that takes `(bool, bool, something)`.

Comment: @scohe001 Impossible to go into details with the given info.   But yes, probably something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a pointer

```
std::unique_ptr<objectname> o;
if(i == 'y')o = std::make_unique<objectname>();
if(j == 'n')o = std::make_unique<objectname>(something);
o->getName();
```

or a lambda

```
objectname o([&i, &j](){
    if(i == 'y')return objectname();
    if(j == 'n')return objectname(something);
    return objectname();
}());
o.getName();
```

if the class has a copy/move constructor

Comment: But he can do the work you post without a pointer as `ClassName objectName o;
if(i == 'y')o = objectName;
if(j == 'n')o = objectName{something};
objectName.getName();`

Comment: In that case you have one unnecessary call to the default constructor. The first solution calls the constructor in the body of the condition and the second condition usually uses copy ellision

Comment: Yes. U R right. Thanks

Comment: Not usually, always